# Jenkins pipeline - Get list of vSphere VMs

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, virtual-machine, vsphere, esx

How can I get list of all the virtual machines in my vSphere cloud from inside a jenkins pipeline?
I couldn't find such an option in the vSphere Plugin for Jenkins.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to "get list of all the virtual machines in my vSphere cloud" leaving Jenkins aside?

Comment: Yes, using the PowerCli command Get-VM: https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-VM.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved by executing powershell script (using the jenkins powershell plugin) that use vSphere PowerCLI command:

> Get-VM

[VMware Get-VM](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FGet-VM.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a *nix alternative, [GOVC's find command](https://github.com/vmware/govmomi/blob/master/govc/USAGE.md#find) is also useful:

```
govc find . -type m
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script. It prints you the list of all vSphere VM names. Use it either in your pipeline or under Manage Jenkins > Script Console:

```
for(mynode in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes)
{
  if(mynode.toComputer().class.metaClass.methods*.name.any{it=='getVmName'})
  {
    vmName = mynode.toComputer().getVmName()
    println "vmName:${vmName}"
  } 
}
```

If you need more details than just the vm names of each jenkins node, then use following script. Uncomment the lines with *NODENAME* if you want to target a specific jenkins node:

```
import hudson.model.Computer.ListPossibleNames
def getCloudDescription(node)  //returns the vSphereCloud info of the node
{
  cloudDescription = ""
  try
  { 
    if(node.toComputer().class.metaClass.methods*.name.any{it=='getCloudDescription'})
    {
        cloudDescription = node.toComputer().getCloudDescription() 
    }
    else
    {
        cloudDescription = "CLOUD_DESCRIPTION_DOESNT_EXIST"
    }
  } 
  catch(exc)
  {
    cloudDescription = "CLOUD_DESCRIPTION_CANT_BE_FOUND"
  }
  return cloudDescription
}

def NODENAME = "WRITE_JENKINSNODE_NAME_HERE"
for(mynode in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes)
{
  //if(NODENAME != mynode.getNodeName()) {continue } 
  nodeName = mynode.getNodeName()
  labels = mynode.getLabelString() 
  //Running state of a Node is called Computer.
  vmName = mynode.toComputer().class.metaClass.methods*.name.any{it=='getVmName'} ? mynode.toComputer().getVmName() : "VM_NAME_DOESNT_EXIST"  
  vsDescription = getCloudDescription(mynode) 
  isOnline = mynode.toComputer().isOnline()
  ipAddress = isOnline ? mynode.toComputer().getChannel().call(new ListPossibleNames())[0] : "NODE_IS_OFFLINE"
  println "nodeName:${nodeName} \t vmName:${vmName} \t vsDescription:${vsDescription} \t labels:${labels} \t isOnline:${isOnline} \t ipAddress:${ipAddress}"
}
```